# What is the name of the following theorem used to prove that rationals are not complete?

Tags: rational-numbers

if $\lambda^2\lt2$ then there exist $\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}, \epsilon\gt0$ such that $(\lambda+\epsilon)^2\lt2$

I've seen it in a proof showing that the set of rational numbers is not complete. It is mentioned also in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612350.

P.S. Since my reputation is below 50 i cannot comment the linked answer to ask them the name of this theorem

Comment: I would not expect this result to have a name.  Most theorems are without name.

Comment: Hint: squaring is a continuous function.

Comment: Also, the author last showed up here six years ago. I doubt commenting would have gotten their attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lulu says, the vast majority of mathematical results are not named. We only name results that we refer to a lot. So it has to be something that is not trivial to reproduce and is widely applicable to many situations.

To show this, if $\lambda$ is rational, and assuming $\lambda > 0$ (replace it by its opposite otherwise), you can choose $$\epsilon = \min\left\{\lambda, \dfrac{2-\lambda^2}{4\lambda}\right\}$$

Then $$\epsilon(2\lambda + \epsilon) < \epsilon(4\lambda) \le 2 - \lambda^2$$
$$\lambda^2 + 2\lambda\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < 2\\(\lambda + \epsilon)^2 < 2$$

If $\lambda$ is not rational, then by the Archimedean principle, there is some integer $n > \max\left\{\dfrac 1\lambda, \dfrac{4\lambda}{2-\lambda^2}\right\}$. Setting $\epsilon = \frac 1n$ gives the same inequalities as above.